# How to pass dbfs path of local dependency wheel file in install_requires field of setup.py

Tags: python, bigdata, databricks, azure-databricks, python-wheel

I am trying to install custom wheel file which requires another wheel file to install from databricks dbfs path. How to provide dbfs path in setup.py **install_requires** section .

Note: I am aware of passing local path but not dbfs path. Can someone help?

I tried to provide path using dbfs:// but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly install or upload wheel  file as shown in the below image.

**Go to cluster -> install library**

[image]

For more information refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/libraries/notebooks-python-libraries) to installing  wheel file.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for .I tried this out. It works. But we are looking for some method which takes care of other local packages from single setup file using "Install_requires"

Comment: Identified a workaround to resolve the issue. Please reach out to me in case of any help.